# SQLite date query returns no record

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I am developing an Android application where I search for records which are created after a given date. My code is some thing like this

```
public List<NPRMember> IncrementalData(String LastDtTime) {

List<NPRMember> results = new ArrayList<NPRMember>();
SQLiteDatabase db=getMyReadableDatabase();
String lastdt="datetime("+LastDtTime+")";
Cursor cursor = null;

try{

      cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_NPR, new String[] { KEY_FULLNAME, KEY_FATHERNAME, 
       KEY_RCRD_SOURCE,KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE},KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE + ">? AND "+KEY_RCRD_SOURCE+">?",
               new String[]{lastdt, "0"}, null, null, null); 


    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            NPRMember nprmem = cursorToMemberDetails(cursor);
            results.add(nprmem);          
            cursor.moveToNext();

    }
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(APP_NAME, "An error occurred while searching for "+LastDtTime+": "+e.toString(), e);
}finally{
    if(cursor!=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursor.close();
    }
}

return results;
```

}

The query does not return any value, although I have at least one record with KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE 2013-07-25 18:59:19
The LastDtTime passed as parameter has value 2013-07-25 14:46:03.
One interesting thing is if I run the query at SQLite command prompt it returns the deisred record.

```
  SELECT fullname, fathername, .... rcrdsource, rcrdcrtndate FROM nprmembers WHERE rcrdcrtndate>'2013-07-25
 14:46:03' AND rcrdsource>0;
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your schema and the data in this table. And please trim away everything that is not necessary tor reproduce your problem

Comment: What happens if you omit the date where clause in your Android app?

Comment: @Frank, without date i get the desired record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter value (in `lastdt`) is wrong.

What you want is the string `2013-07-25 18:59:19`, but you are actually using the string `datetime(2013-07-25 18:59:19)`.
The letter `d` comes after `2`, so no record matches.

Change the initialization of `lastdt` to:

```
String lastdt=LastDtTime;
```

Comment: I am trying to retrieve KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE  greater than LastDtTime passed as parameter. In my case 2013-07-25 18:59:19 (KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE)> 2013-07-25 14:46:03 (LastDtTime), so the function should retrieve a record.

Comment: In your code, `lastdt` is not the same as `LastDtTime`. You must remove the `datetime`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Does that mean sqlite date works on string comparison? Wondering, why datetime(KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE)>datetime(LastDtTime) does not work

Comment: my date in sqlite is stored as Text. Please see this answer [K_Anas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832864/compare-dates-stored-as-string-in-android-sqlite-database). It says KEY_RCRD_CRN_DATE> Datetime('2013-07-25 14:46:03') should work. Though it does not work for me. confused.

Comment: `datetime('...')` is an SQL expression, but parameters are not expressions but plain values.