# sql - sqlite select with condition on date

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite table with due_date. I would like to execute a query to select those records where due_date >= 2017/01/20:

> SELECT  * FROM todo WHERE 1 = 1  AND date(due_date) >=
>   date('2017-01-20') AND task_name LIKE '%%';

Comment: check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832864/compare-dates-stored-as-string-in-android-sqlite-database

Comment: What is the format that you're using to store the date values?

Comment: @CL Yes, I store due_date with type DATE in the database.

Comment: I did no ask about the column type but the specific type of the values. (SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).)