# how to compare string date with the format "dd-MM-yyyy" to empty string

Tags: android, sqlite

hello guys for the last three days I have been working on a simple query , but it is just not working , I'm trying to prevent register departure without having registered arrival , here is the code in my **DB helper**,not sure what is wrong with that query!!

```
public Boolean HasShowedUpToday(int check_id)
{  
    Boolean attend;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    time=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String dateoftoday= dateFormat.format(time);       
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM attendance where user_id = '"+check_id+"' and arrival_time ='"+dateoftoday+"' and departure_time ='';", null);
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {

        attend=true;
    }
    else
    {
        attend=false;
    }
    return attend;
}
```

Comment: locale when operating on database? Locale is important when communicating with user not with database!

Comment: @ Marek R  so should i change the format that i have saved it with in db ?

Comment: Why there are extra ' in your query? Don't you think it should be like this -> `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM attendance where user_id = "+check_id+" and arrival_time ="+dateoftoday+" and departure_time =;", null);`

Comment: actually it is important otherwise the app crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not construct queries like that. This is very wrong habit which will made you in future to write code which is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Use [rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).
So it should look like this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM attendance where user_id = ? and arrival_time = ? and departure_time IS NULL", 
                       new String[] { check_id, dateoftoday} );
```

Also take a look on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833223/1387438). And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694823/1387438) looks even better - store dates as number of milliseconds since EPOCH time.